# Dynamically create subscribe event - knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am creating fields dynamically in knockout. The code below will create a textbox or a drop down select list. The input fields are bound to the property "Response", which I also subscribe to. When the user changes the select list, I want to know what type of control was used (e.g. Textbox or DropDownList). My problem is knockout is telling me the wrong type always; Textbox, which is the last field created:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var fields = [{
    "Label": "Enter The State",
    "Length": 75,
    "Type": "DropDownList",
    "IsRequired": true,
    "PreValue": "New York, New Jersey",
    "Response": ""
  }, {
    "Label": "Enter Reason",
    "Length": 75,
    "Type": "DropDownList",
    "IsRequired": true,
    "PreValue": "Good,Bad,Ugly",
    "Response": ""
  }, {
    "Label": "Enter City",
    "Length": 75,
    "Type": "TextBox",
    "IsRequired": true,
    "PreValue": "",
    "Response": ""
  }];

/* knockout */
function DynamicFormViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.fields = fields;
    self.selectItem = function(value, text) {
      this.value = value;
      this.text = text;
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < self.fields.length; i++) {
      var field = self.fields[i];
      if (field.Type == 'TextBox') {
        field.Response = ko.observable(field.PreValue);
      } else if (field.Type === 'DropDownList') {
        field.Items = [];
        var itms = field.PreValue.split(",");
        field.Items.push(new self.selectItem('', '--' + field.Label + '--'));
        for (var s = 0; s < itms.length; s++) {
          var sItem = new self.selectItem(itms[s], itms[s]);
          field.Items.push(sItem);
        }
        field.Response = ko.observable(field.PreValue);
      } else {
        field.Response = ko.observable(field.PreValue);
      }
      field.Response.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if (newValue !== undefined && newValue != null && newValue.length > 0) {
         alert(field.Type);
        }
      });
   };
  };
  var viewModel = new DynamicFormViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

});
```

Here is a working example: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PhillyNJ/uh3a6193/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable "field" in your Response subscription is being altered by the surrounding loop so the reference is always the last item in the loop.

You can change the subscription function to pass in the context it should use for its "this" variable and use that instead.

```
field.Response.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  if (newValue !== undefined && newValue != null && newValue.length > 0) {
    alert(this.Type);
  }
}, field);
```